# Where do I find cursor files in windows 7

Tags: c#, wpf, mouse-cursor

I know that the I can get a set of cursor files in C:/Windows/Cursors. However, I want to know where the cursor files are for when you do a DragDropEffect in C# WPF. Is this available?

Comment: Those aren't actual files, AFAIK

Comment: oh...is there any way to get the cursor file for that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are built-in as resources.  In Visual Studio, use File + Open + File and select c:\windows\system32\ole32.dll.  Open the Cursor node and double-click one of the numbered items to look at the cursor.  You can copy them to a file by right-clicking the resource and select Export.  Not really sure about the legality, it probably isn't.